# How to generate navigation map/graph of MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki

I’m trying to generate sort of map or graph from a MediaWiki that shows the interconnection of categories and pages as a graph, to enhance navigability of the wiki.

I’ve found that GraphViz can do this, but I was wondering if there are any easier or better ways to accomplish this.
It doesn’t have to be a plugin, I’m fine by exporting my WiKi to XML and importing it to a third party program to create the map/graph as I don’t often update my wiki.

Answer (score 0):

There is the extension CategoryTree that "provides a dynamic view of the wiki's category structure as a tree".